# Aura create component with using JS

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

How to add new component with using standard JQ or JS methods?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using lightning out
$Lightning.createComponent can be used.
If its within visualforce, you dont have to pass the session Id , if you plan to use it in a different web app you have to pass the sessionId .

or if you are trying to create it after the $A is loaded , the same method can be used as $A.createComponent.

may be the links below can help

[Dynamically creating components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm)

[Lightning out authentication](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_out_authentication.htm)

[Lightning out in visualforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_visualforce.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use pure Javascript or any other library like jQuery. Soon, in Lightning will be much difficult use some important pure javascript feature, like the DOM manipulation because this critical update "Enable Lightning LockerService Security". For more details, see [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/04/introducing-lockerservice-lightning-components.html)